# ICMP Destination unreachable (Port unreachable) error

Tags: udp, port, router, ip-camera, icmp

I will describe the problem that I encounter below which is the error message that I can see in WireShark:
**ICMP Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)**

I am connecting an IP Camera like this:
**IP Camera --> Router(no internet connected) --> My PC Computer**

- IP Camera IP Address: 192.168.1.101
- PC Ethernet IP Address: 192.168.1.104
- I have disabled all firewalls in Windows 10 and have no antivirus software

(Above 2 IP are put as static IP Address Reservations in the TP-Link Router)

Now I use some code that I have (I will try to not post the code as I dont think that is the problem).
When I run the code, I use WireShark to sniff out what the problem is and I get as seen in image below this error message:

**ICMP Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)**

I have googled on this error message and I have red almost every post I can find but no one really tells how to solve this problem. Only what it means.

The image shows the error. However each time I run the code, the source/destination ports changes everytime so they are not static. It could be for example those ports as I tried the code at least 3 times:

Source ports: 65063,64077,51923 etc (PC computer)
Destination ports: 6987,6991,6995 etc (IP Camera)

What is causing this error and what can I do to solve this error?

*(Image from WireShark)*
[image]

Comment: Is caused by sending a datagram via a UDP socket that is connected to a destination that doesn't exist, for example a UDP port at the target that isn't opened by an application.

Comment: Okay so does that mean that the IP Camera is sending a datagram via a UDP socket to my computer and application where the port in the application is not open?

Comment: Whoever received the ICMP message did the sending.

Comment: Okey, then if I can understand when looking at the WireShark log in my post, it says that Destination: 192.168.1.101 which is the IP Cameras IP address. Does that mean that some port should be opened in the IP Camera? I am just guessing now or do I misunderstand this? At the same time it says destination 192.168.1.104(PC computer) in the green text in the image above which confuses alot. Is the IP Camera or PC the destination? in above red rectangle error?

Comment: If I understand the dump correctly, the destination of the refused datagram was 192.168.1.101:6995. So if that's the camera, your application is sending to its port 6995, and it isn't open. Maybe you're sending to the wrong port, or maybe you need to configure the camera somehow,

Comment: Yes thats the way I try to interpret the error also now with what you have described that the refused datagram was 192.168.1.101:6995 which is the camera as I put it as static in the router. The application seems to send on different ports everytime I run the code but it is around ports 6987-6995. Yes you are right. Perheps I need to configure somthing in the camera. It was not possible to do any such configurations with the app that followed. But if it is possible to understand that the problem lies in the camera it is a good start.

Comment: It doesn't matter what port the application sends *from,* and it will certainly be different every time you run it unless you bind your socket to a soeific port. But events have already proven that you don't need to do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about computer programming, just application and camera configuration.

Comment: Okay so if the application sends on different ports each time, I wonder how a configuration in the camera can be possible if I could only choose to open one port?

Comment: Oh yes okay I understand, is it off topic?

Comment: It doesn't matter what port you send from. The camera will reply to whatever that port was. It only matters what port you send to, and you have that wrong somehow. You need to either configure the camera to use port 6995 or comfigure the application to use whatever port the camera is using, or maybe enable something in the camera that is presently off.